# JSOUP extracting a href title

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I have got HTML:

```
<h2 class="p-job-title">
       <a href="/work/android-software" rel="nofollow" 
        title="work Android - Software Developer" class="job-offer ">
   <strong class="keyword">Android</strong> - Software <strong class="keyword">Developer</strong>
            </a>
          </h2>
```

How can I extract the title ("work Android - Software Developer") from within an href? I don't need href, just title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it exactly the same as with any other attribute. You pick tag with attribute, in your case `<a ...>` with `href` and `title` like

```
Elements hrefs = doc.select("a[href][title]");
```

and then you pick attribute from tag using `tag.attr("attributeName")`

```
for (Element el : hrefs){
    System.out.println(el.attr("title"));
}
```

BTW if you are sure that only one element was selected, or you want to read `title` from first tag selected you can invoke `attr` method on `Elements` representing group of selected tags.

```
System.out.println(doc.select("a[href][title]").attr("title"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really quite simple! And how to modify it to extract href titles but only from within <h2 class="p-job-title"> ?

Comment: If you take a look at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax you will find that suntax for parent and child is `parent child` which means you need to describe parent, place space and describe which child you want to select. In your case it can be `select("h2.p-job-title a[href][title]")`.

Comment: That is what I figured out on my own right now :) Either way thanks for help! :)